# Question of the value of the following double sum

Tags: summation, bessel-functions

I hope to get the exact value of the following double series:

$$ \sum_{k \geq 0} \sum_{n \geq 0} \binom{2k}{ k} \frac{(-1)^n}{n! (2k+2n+1) 2^{4k+2n+1}}. $$

I am not sure it is possible or not.
I need your comments.

Comment: Are the sums going to infinity?

Comment: yes, in the both sums.

Comment: Seems to sum to 0.481561... Start with the sum over $n$. So drop the sum over $k$, the binomial coefficient and a factor $2^{-2k-1}$ (leaving $2^{-2k-2n}$. That gives $\Gamma[0.5+k,0,0.25]$ (incomplete gamma).

Comment: If the $2n+2k+1$ factor from the denominator would be absent, the sum would be $\dfrac1{\sqrt{3\sqrt e}}$

Answer (score 1):

You can write your double series as:
$$\begin{eqnarray*}\color{red}{S}&=&\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{k\geq 0}\sum_{n\geq 0}\binom{2k}{k}16^{-k}x^{2k}\frac{(-1)^n}{4^n\,n!}x^{2n}\,dx\\&=&\int_{0}^{1}\frac{e^{-x^2/4}}{\sqrt{4-x^2}}dx=\int_{0}^{1/2}\frac{dx}{e^{x^2}\sqrt{1-x^2}}=\color{red}{\int_{0}^{\pi/6}e^{-\sin^2\theta}d\theta},\end{eqnarray*}$$
but I would not bet that the last integral can be written in terms of elementary functions. 
Numerically, we have:
$$ S = 0.481561249\ldots $$
A fast converging series arises from considering the Fourier series of $e^{-\sin^2\theta}$:
$$e^{-\sin^2\theta}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{e}}I_0(1/2)+\frac{2}{\sqrt{e}}\sum_{m=1}^{+\infty}I_m(1/2)\cos(2m\theta),$$

> $$ S = \frac{\pi}{6\sqrt{e}}I_0(1/2)+\frac{1}{\sqrt{e}}\sum_{m=1}^{+\infty}\frac{I_m(1/2)}{m}\sin\frac{\pi m}{3},$$

where $I_\alpha(\cdot)$ is the modified [Bessel function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function) of the first kind.

Comment: Numerically, S=0.481561...

Comment: Is that $x^{4k}$ or $x^{2k}$?

Comment: Yes, there was a typo, I wrote $x^4$ in place of $x^2$, fixed.

Comment: If the upper integration limit would be $2$ instead of $1$, or $\dfrac\pi2$ instead of $\dfrac\pi6$, then the value of the integral would be $\dfrac\pi{2~\sqrt e}~\text{BesselI}\bigg(0,~\dfrac12\bigg)$. But since there are no “incomplete” [Bessel functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function), I am equally skeptical about the possible existence of a closed form expression.

Comment: @Lucian: I was going to say it. Anyway, we can consider the Fourier cosine series of $e^{-\sin^2\theta}$ and integrate it termwise: we get a very fast converging series.

Comment: Do you think it is the case to use the brand new "bessel-functions" tag?

Comment: Yes, it would appear so.

Comment: This problem came from the question by one of my colleagues: what is the exact value of the following definite integral,

Answer (score 0):

This problem came from the question asked by one of my friends. What is the exact 
value of the following definite integral

$$ \int_0^{1/2} \frac{exp(-x^2)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} dx ? $$

So, I got the corresponding Taylor series, multiply both of them.
I need closed form for the value, that is, which doesn't have the summation
notation.